# How can I do " when I click other button counter change"

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have two buttons my site. here are like and dislike buttons. And I have one counter. When I click the button increase the counter. In the present situation once I click the like button. I can't dislike I mean I clicked the dislike button but my decision has changed and I want to click like button. What can I do for this?
Sorry for my English.

```
var button = document.getElementById("btn");
var buttonFlag = false;
button.addEventListener("click", onClick);

function onClick() {
  if (buttonFlag) return;
  console.log("Clicked");
  buttonFlag = true;
}
```

I expect the button --- When I click the like counter = +1 when I click the dislike counter = -1

Comment: first, I don't see any increment logic. Secondly, you only referenced one `button` (just in case, `ID`s must be unique in a webpage). Thirdly, what does `buttonFlag` do.

Comment: My understanding here is that you would like two buttons? First button to +1 the counter? Second button to -1 the counter? Like this? https://stackoverflow.com/a/57441142/8526705

Comment: Please see my answer, I think it fully answers your question.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go!!

```js
var count = 0;

function dolikes(add) {
  if (add) {
    count++;
  } else {
    count--;
  }
  if (count >= 0) {
    document.getElementById('count').innerText = count;
  } else {
    count = 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<button onclick="dolikes('add')">Like</button>

<div id="count">0</div>

<button onclick="dolikes()">Dislike</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
const counterDisplay = document.getElementById("counter")

window.counter = 0

function Like() {
  counter += 1
  counterDisplay.innerText = counter
}

function Dislike() {
  if (counter > 0) counter -= 1
  counterDisplay.innerText = counter
}
```

```html
<button onclick="Like()">Like</button>
<button onclick="Dislike()">Dislike</button>

<span id="counter">0</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

To increment or decrement a counter variable from two buttons sharing a common "click handler", you could do the following:

```js
var counter = 0;

function onClick(event) {

  if(event.currentTarget.classList.contains('like')) {
    counter += 1;
  }
  
  if(event.currentTarget.classList.contains('dislike')) {
    counter -= 1;
  }

  console.log(counter);

  document.querySelector('p span').innerText = counter;
}

document.querySelector('.like').addEventListener('click', onClick);
document.querySelector('.dislike').addEventListener('click', onClick);
```

```html
<button class="like">Like</button>
<button class="dislike">Dislike</button>
<p>Counter:<span></span></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yeah that's my want.But I have to button add function.Just once click. One user have to once click.

```js
var counter = 0;

function onClick(event) {

  if(event.currentTarget.classList.contains('like')) {
    counter += 1;
  }
  
  if(event.currentTarget.classList.contains('dislike')) {
    counter -= 1;
  }

  console.log(counter);

  document.querySelector('p span').innerText = counter;
}

document.querySelector('.like').addEventListener('click', onClick);
document.querySelector('.dislike').addEventListener('click', onClick);
```

```html
<button class="like">Like</button>
<button class="dislike">Dislike</button>
<p>Counter:<span></span></p>
```

Comment: You can use `localStorage` or `cookie` for user control. You mark any user with `localStorage` or `cookie`, and marked user cannot press those buttons. However, the user can modify and delete this data and is also unsafe. Therefore, you should check these controls at back-end instead of JavaScript

Comment: Please see my answer as it adress your issue. @Eren

Answer (score 0):

**Here is the logic:**

Lets say our upvote value is "0".

The user upvotes a comment. That value is now "1".

The user then changes its mind and downvotes it. The value is now "-1", not 0.

The user cannot upvote/downvote multiple times.

**EDIT:** I added a "cancel vote" function: the user can click "upvote" two times to first, upvote and a second time to reset the vote.

To verify if the user upvoted/downvoted I verify the innerHTML status of the buttons (Ex toggled on is "`[upvote]`" and toggled off its `upvote`)

Here it is in action:

```js
    function del(){
      //Get vote status
      upvote=document.getElementById("upvote");
      downvote=document.getElementById("downvote");
      //Get counter
      count=document.getElementById("count");

      //Reverb back vote to before
      if(upvote.innerHTML=="[upvote]"){
        //The user upvoted, reset vote
        count.innerHTML=parseInt(count.innerHTML)-1;
        //Reset styling
        upvote.innerHTML="upvote";
      }else{//The user downvoted, reset vote
        count.innerHTML=parseInt(count.innerHTML)+1;
        downvote.innerHTML="downvote";
      }
    upvote.href="javascript:change('0')";
    downvote.href="javascript:change('1')";
    }
    function change(arg){
      //Get upvote count
      count=document.getElementById("count");
      //Get links
      upvote=document.getElementById("upvote");
      downvote=document.getElementById("downvote");
      
      if(arg==0){
        //If user wants to upvote
      
        //add effect to upvote button
        upvote.innerHTML="[upvote]";
        upvote.href="javascript:del()";
      
        //Update counter
        if(downvote.innerHTML=="[downvote]"){
          //If the user downvoted before
          //Add two votes instead of one
          count.innerHTML=parseInt(count.innerHTML)+2;
        }else{//User didnt downvoted before, add 1
        count.innerHTML=parseInt(count.innerHTML)+1;
        }
        
        //Reset downvote styling
        downvote.innerHTML="downvote";
        downvote.href="javascript:change('1')";
      }
      if(arg==1){
        //If user wants to downvote
        
        //Make downvote unclickable
        downvote.innerHTML="[downvote]";
        downvote.href="javascript:del()";
        
        //Update counter
        if(upvote.innerHTML=="[upvote]"){
          //If the user upvoted before
          //Remove two votes instead of one
          count.innerHTML=parseInt(count.innerHTML)-2;
        }else{//User didnt upvote before, remove 1
        count.innerHTML=parseInt(count.innerHTML)-1;
        }
        //Reset upvote styling
        upvote.innerHTML="upvote";
        upvote.href="javascript:change('0')";
      }
    }
```

```html
    <a href="javascript:change('0')" id="upvote">Upvote</a> or <a href="javascript:change('1')" id="downvote">Downvote</a><br>

    <div id="count">50</div>
```

Hope this helps!